# Cycling through Text File and capture a string value

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Getting the Specified content into the buffer in c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6292223/getting-the-specified-content-into-the-buffer-in-c)

I have a text file as shown Below.

```
<HTML>
<BODY>
Hello, User
<BODY>
<HTML>
```

I need a C program to Capture Hello, User into a buffer variable.. 
Can anyone please help me..
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this your homework? You should really be doing this yourself if it is... how will you learn otherwise? You should also provide what you have already done when you post a question.

Here is a very bare-bones solution.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define SIZE_OF_BUFFER 255
#define FILENAME "yourpage.html"
#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0

/* Read the contents of the (first) BODY tag into buffer */
int main(void)
{
    int next_read = FALSE;
    char buffer[SIZE_OF_BUFFER] = {'\0'};
    FILE *htmlpage;

    htmlpage = fopen(FILENAME, "r");
    if(htmlpage ==  NULL)
    {
        printf("Couldn't locate file - exiting...");
        return -1;
    }

    while(fscanf(htmlpage, " %[^\n]s", buffer) != EOF)
    {
        if(strncmp(buffer, "<BODY>", 6) == 0)
        {
            next_read = TRUE;
        }
        else if(next_read == TRUE)
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    fclose(htmlpage);

    if(next_read == TRUE)
    {
        /* print the contents of buffer */
        printf("%s\n", buffer);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("No <BODY> tag found in file!\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```